# Pagination - standard php or without page reloading with ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pagination

I've been searching lately but didn't find any info about this.

Is there a difference between these 2 types of pagination? The most bugging question is how the speed of data executions are? Which is better to use for slower networks?

Comment: Of course ajax pagination will be faster. Selection of ajax or non-ajax pagination depends on your requirement.

Comment: Impossible to say without more specs. Ignore what @Dr.Dan said however: certain dataset and browser combinations might make it slower for the user (the point where javascript comes in).

Comment: Ajax is good for slower networks because you don't load full html page while using ajax. User's computer loads only a small piece of data and javascript handles it. Many of the work is done by user's computer.

Comment: You should allow both Ajax and HTTP based pagination anyway, users without javascript and search engines with otherwise not be able to navigate within your pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods will have to retrieve the results from server side in your case I assume it would be php.
As the retrieval of results in both methods are the same, then difference lays in sending data over and displaying.
With standard php pagination you need to send whole page, with all the layout and other necessary stuff for your page, not to mention all the new calls to libraries that are requested with new page load.
When doing AJAX pagination, you will most likely send over only the data, for example, in JSON format and then create the necessary elements in javascript on user side, or if you choose to do send over already ready HTML code and simply insert that in DOM.

In conclusion, I would say that AJAX version is definitely faster.

Not talking about performance there are several other aspects that should affect your decision. Here are few:

- As other commenters have mentioned, be vary of cases when user has turned off javascript;
- Search engines can't index these results then (need confirmation on this one);
- Think about back/forward navigation.

Comment: If you create it using ajax as an enhancement, then the default method of page refresh will work when javascript is unavailable, so search engines could see the results. The method of calculating pagination is also worth mentioning. ie run query to find number of results, then either loop through or SEEK the results required for displaying OR re-run the query with LIMITs

Comment: What about SEO when using ajax pagination?

Answer (score 1):

An ajax pagination should be faster than reloading the whole page, because you need to update only the fragment with your resultset and not all the assets again (with their payload, headers and latency time).

If you also plan carefully the data format sent by the server — e.g. JSON instead of plain HTML you could use along a client-side templating engine  —  you could even reduce the payload with great benefit for the overall response time.

Moreover, if your page contains scripts to be executed at every page load, then some extra time will be always spent by javascript interpreter at every page load, while with ajax you will execute scripts once (and if you need to re-apply some functionality to elements of your resultset you coud take benefit from event delegation)

Comment: If someone could explain his downvote I could improve my answer or corrct myself for the good of the community, thank you

Comment: I think that a fair, unbiased and with a knowledge-of-the-facts downvote can be always explained. Maybe this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with the concept of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).  It's a concept that states that, if Javascript isn't available, the site still works.

Also, [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) which is a concept of adding more layers of functionality by starting out with accessibility in mind.

I would say that best practice would be to:

a) Implement Pagination server side (PHP)
b) Layer on Javascript (Ajax/jQuery)

> Is there a difference between these 2 types of pagination?

Pagination is pagination.  There's no real difference between the function, just the execution.

> The most bugging question is how the speed of data executions are?

AJAX will certainly feel faster and often be faster thanks no not having to re-render an entire page and all that overhead.  Of course, it also adds an extra layer that could break if not programmed well.

> Which is better to use for slower networks?

That depends.  Are you thinking cellular network speeds?  If so, how optimized is the site for mobile?  Are you just thinking desktops and dial-up?

(A) You can also program AJAX like pagination differently.  You could load all the results at once, and then use Javascript to chop up the results into "pages".  Effectively having all the HTML markup there and just show/hidding it when needed.

(B) You could only load the first page and have AJAX calls back to the server to load additional pages.

**Good**

Option (A) works well if people are likely going to view multiple pages.  It makes only 1 trip to the server, on page load, and you just use Javascript to present it in an easier to read fashion.

Option (B) works well if people are not likely to view most pages.

**Bad**

Option (A) you could load far more data than needed, making the initial page load slower (but only some because there's overhead there already, depending on the result list size.)

Option (B) If people view many pages, you could be making more calls across the network to load data, which could be a slow experience if it's long to load any given data set.

I hope that helps some!